# Best algorithm to find N unique random numbers in VERY large array

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, bigdata, asymptotic-complexity

I have an array with, for example, 1000000000000 of elements (integers). What is the best approach to pick, for example, only 3 random and unique elements from this array? Elements must be unique in whole array, not in list of N (3 in my example) elements.

I read about Reservoir sampling, but it provides only method to pick random numbers, which can be non-unique.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but could you just choose 3 random numbers, check to see if they're equal to each other if they are, choose another?

Comment: I believe Guy is after 3 random numbers which are unique within the whole array.

Comment: Elements must be unique in array, not in sample of 3 elements.

Comment: So reduce the problem: first find the unique values, then select randomly among them.

Comment: In an array of that size (if it's unsorted), even proving that any element is unique will take considerable time.

Comment: I thinked about it. But how can I to find unique elements very fast in so large array?

Comment: @GuyFawkes You can't. You need to pre-process your array one way or another. You can sort it for example, that will make searching for uniques very fast. And there are fairly efficient algorithms for in-place sorting on disk, mergesort is a good initial candidate.

Comment: How big are your integers?  You can do it in O(N) by counting instances of each value, in MAXINT space.

Comment: Comparing evey element against everyother to check uniqueness is out of the question. Perhaps try sorting the array first then select a random position and check if the next element (or previous for the first) is the same, if so skip otherwise take that as your first then repeat. All you need is the most efficient sorting algorithm.

Comment: The fastest way I can think on is to loop through the list and counting occurrences using some fast-access hash table and then return the first `k` keys which value is exactly `1`. This would be `O(N+M)` where N for looping the list and construct the hash table and `M < N` the iterations needed to find the first `k` unique numbers.

Comment: I thinked about hash table to get unique elements. I also read about better solution with graph, but cannot find it. But I think sorting and even for (i = 0; i < size; i++) is very slow.

Comment: To find exact unique numbers (not *probable* unique numbers) you need to iterate the whole list at least once. If you still think that is too slow... Try some GPU or parallel algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the odds of hitting a non-unique value are low, your best bet will be to select 3 random numbers from the array, then check each against the entire array to ensure it is unique - if not, choose another random sample to replace it and repeat the test.

If the odds of hitting a non-unique value are high, this increases the number of times you'll need to scan the array looking for uniqueness and makes the simple solution non-optimal. In that case you'll want to split the task of ensuring unique numbers from the task of making a random selection.

Sorting the array is the easiest way to find duplicates. Most sorting algorithms are O(n log n), but since your keys are integers [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) can potentially be faster.

Another possibility is to use a hash table to find duplicates, but that will require significant space. You can use a smaller hash table or [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to identify potential duplicates, then use another method to go through that smaller list.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = [0] * (MAXINT-MININT+1)
for value in Elements:
  counts[value] += 1
uniques = [c for c in counts where c==1]
result = random.pick_3_from(uniques)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a reasonable idea what fraction of the array values are likely to be unique.  So you would know, for instance, that if you picked 1000 random array values, the odds are good that one is unique.

Step 1.  Pick 3 random hash algorithms.  They can all be the same algorithm, except that you add different integers to each as a first step.

Step 2.  Scan the array.  Hash each integer all three ways, and for each hash algorithm, keep track of the X lowest hash codes you get (you can use a priority queue for this), and keep a hash table of how many times each of those integers occurs.

Step 3.  For each hash algorithm, look for a unique element in that bucket.  If it is already picked in another bucket, find another.  (Should be a rare boundary case.)

That is your set of three random unique elements.  Every unique triple should have even odds of being picked.

(Note: For many purposes it would be fine to just use one hash algorithm and find 3 things from its list...)

This algorithm will succeed with high likelihood in one pass through the array.  What is better yet is that the intermediate data structure that it uses is fairly small and is amenable to merging.  Therefore this can be parallelized across machines for a very large data set.